# C++ и стандартный GUI Windows

Tags: gui, qt, c++

Доброго времени суток! Я начинающий программист C++, и планирую программировать интерфейс своей программы с помощью QT. Собственно, вопрос в том, нужны ли будут библиотеки QT для запуска программы на другом компьютере (и можно ли их сразу включить в exe-шник)? И возможно ли программировать интерфейс с помощью стандартных средств языка? Заранее спасибо!

Comment: если вопрос предусматривает деплой приложения - то присоединюсь...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Есть 2 пути сборки вашего проекта со сторонними библиотеками (в том числе и с Qt) для распространения: *статическая* и *динамическая* линковка.

При *статической* линковке двоичные символы (*.lib), например, Qt, будут включены в состав вашего EXEшника (или DLL, - смотря что собираете), и специально их распространять вместе с программой **не придется**.

При *динамической* линковке используются двоичные символы, собранные в *.dll файлах библиотеки, и, следовательно, в вашем EXEшнике будут только ссылки на них, так что вместе с программой **придется распространять и сторонние dll**.

Каждое решение имеет как свои плюсы, так и недостатки, об этом можно найти массу информации в сети.

---

А еще следует заглянуть в лицензию на ту же Qt - ее, кажется, статически линковать без приобретения коммерческой версии нельзя.

---

P.S. Уважаемый [[@mikillskegg](/users/751/mikillskegg)](/users/751/mikillskegg) о GUI и С++ все сообщил.

Answer (score 3):

Библиотеки будут нужны. Включить их в виндовский экзешник, кажется, можно (сам на Qt под виндой никогда не работал).

Программировать GUI с помощью стандартных средств С++ нельзя, потому что стандарт такого не предусматривает по ряду веских причин.

Comment: Спасибо за ваш ответ. А есть какие-нибудь другие способы, кроме QT?

Comment: Конечно есть. Кроссплатформенные библиотеки GTK+, wxWidgets и другие. В виндовсе есть своие фреймворке и в крайнем случае можно голые WinAPI использовать.

Comment: Спасибо огромное!